# ListView: обновление данных сбивает ChekBox

Tags: java, android, listview, checkbox

Есть ListView состоящий из CheckBox. Пихаю в него ArrayList. По ходу работы приложения массив изменяется и надо обновить список.

```
//#1
listview.invalidateViews();

//#2
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Эти 2 способа обновляют список на ура. Но все CheckBox'ы скидываются в дефолтное положение. Причем именно скидываются, а не выключаются (ну это и логично).

А вот следующий способ сохраняет статус CheckBox'ов, но имена (которые тянутся из массива) съезжают.

```
list.requestLayout();
```

Как обновить ListView и сохранить статус CheckBox'ов?

Comment: В качестве элемента массива используйте объект со свойством Cheked. Оно должно меняться с вместе с изменением Checked в списке (нужно прописать событие). При обновлении прокатитесь по массиву и установите соответствие свойства Checked элемента списка "прикрученному" элементу массива. Я бы мог привести пример, но только на C#.

Comment: @Rekssel сложно. т.к. потом встанет вопрос, как этот объект со свойством Cheked записать в SharedPreferences. вот если бы знать, как обратиться к каждому Item'у.

Comment: Так ведь проблема в том, что "галки" привязаны к **позициям** в списке. Даже получив "доступ" вы всё равно узнаете только позицию, которая точно так же как и "галка" потеряет актуальность после добавления новых элементов. Поэтому единственный вариант сохранять состояние "чёкнутости" при изменяющемся списке - это хранить его в самом элементе данных. В плане сохранения, конечно, `SharedPreferences` не особо удобен. Но это ж не единственно доступный вариант.

Comment: @woesss ну да, уже разобрался. использовал ответ выше, и в кастомном адаптере подкручивал boolean массив состояния ЧекБоксов. но все ровно, странно, что без этого, даже при прокрутке ListView спадают галки.